# Duty cycle detection circuit for square wave

Tags: comparator, integrator, digital-comparator, phase-detector

I have two signals coming out of one block. One signal is one period delayed than the other one. Is there any method to detect the duty cycle of these pulses?.
[image]

Edit:
Clk is my original signal. Going to two blocks . Have two outputs clk_1 and clk_2. Having different pulse width compared to the original signal. I want to detect if such a case is happening. That is if the duty cycle of the two signals coming out is different to the original signal.

Comment: Frequecy, pulse voltage (=draw the shape, too), wanted resolution, accepted calculation delay, is long time constant averaging an acceptable estimation method, should the result be a binary number or voltage? At first: make sure that we use term "Duty cycle" in the same way.

Comment: Why do you want to 'detect' the duty cycle, and what form should the 'detection' take? _"One signal is one period delayed than the other one."_ - What does this mean exactly? Can you us show a timing diagram?

Comment: Added the timing diagram in the op

Comment: @Ynwa What's the time of a full cycle? How much loading can be accepted by the node being monitored? What's the high voltage? How fast do you expect detection? Are phase differences to be entirely ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Detecting the duty cycle of a square wave of Known peak amplitude is easy if you are not in a hurry.

Say if your peak is 5VDC then just average this with a lowpass filter. For non critical stuff one or two passive RC sections will do. Make your cut frequency a small fraction of your square wave frequency so the output will be low ripple DC.

Feed the DC through a simple comparetor like say LM393. 1V is 20%, 2.5V is 50% 4V is 80% etc.

Comment: Is there any possibility of finding the average value using CMOS ? Using rc circuit is difficult in our case because if area limitations

Comment: Hi Autistic! I've got a command that I run on your posts to make the punctuation right, I think it might be of interest to you: If you put your text in a file called `foo.txt` and then run $$\,$$```sed -i 's/ \([\.,!]\)/\1 /g' foo.txt```$$\,$$it places the punctuation before the space, not after :)

Comment: Nice answer, by the way :) If you want to add something: with a simple non-inverting Schmitt trigger IC, one can bring a square wave to a well-defined known amplitude and apply your method!

Comment: @Ynwa Um, a RC filter would need a high-value resistor and a capacitor, both in regions that you'd normally buy in SMD 0402 or smaller. I don't think a CMOS solution would be getting smaller than two passives.

Comment: @Ynwa If you want a solution that uses only CMOS and you have a size restriction then you need to add that information to your original question...don't leave it in a comment.